# Funny result when adding negated logical values together

Tags: r

Consider

```
> TRUE + FALSE
[1] 1
```

Now, set up a situation where something evaluates to a logical using the `is.na` function and the negation operator `!`:

```
> x = NA
> y = "not NA"
```

Evaluate to `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
> !is.na(x)
[1] FALSE

> !is.na(y)
[1] TRUE
```

But,

```
> !is.na(x) + !is.na(y)
[1] FALSE
```

This is strange. Adding extra brackets seems to fix it, but why is this happening?

```
> (!is.na(x)) + (!is.na(y))
[1] 1
```

Comment: I believe it's because the first `!` carries through the whole expression if not bracketed, and so it is negating the value of `is.na(x) + !is.na(y)` (which is 2 - and also TRUE)

Comment: That would indeed explain this behaviour, which seems very counter-intuitive to me. Is the order of operations documented somewhere?

Comment: `?Syntax` has some information and a few links

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `?Syntax`.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to operator precedence. See `?Syntax` `+` precedes `!`. There are two ways

```
!is.na(x) + !is.na(y)
```

could be interpreted:

```
`!`(`+`(is.na(x), !is.na(y)))
```

or

```
`+`(`!`(is.na(x)), !is.na(y))
```

R interprets the expression the first way due to the order of operator precedence. Compare this to

```
!is.na(x) & !is.na(y)
```

here R interpretes the expression as

```
`&`(`!`(is.na(x)), !is.na(y))
```

as `!` precedes `&`.